# NextJS useEffect locaStorage issue

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Iam trying to get the string from localstorage and check that with some condition and redirect the page based on the value from localstorage

but the problem is, i could see the page for couple of seconds even before it redirects to origin page

basically its authentication kind of thing

here is the code

```
import React from "react";
import AdminDashboard from "../components/AdminDashboard";
import Router from "next/router";
import SignIn from "../pages/index";
import useRouter from "next/router";
import fetch from "isomorphic-unfetch";

var userType;
export default function Test({ token }) {
  const [userType, setuserType] = React.useState(false);

  React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if (userType !== true) {
      const lt = localStorage.getItem("userType");
      if (lt !== true) Router.push("/");
    }
    return () => {};
  }, []);
  {
    console.log(token);
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <AdminDashboard>Admin Page </AdminDashboard>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: i think you can't store boolean values i local storage, check for the value and the type of lt

Answer (score 0):

You can render the page in the client only to avoid page flashing.

On the other hands, You can just using useEffect.

```
const Page = null;

React.useEffect(() => {
    if (userType !== true) {
      const lt = localStorage.getItem("userType");
      if (lt !== true) Router.push("/");
    } else {
      Page = (
        <div>
          <AdminDashboard>Admin Page </AdminDashboard>
        </div>
      )
    }
}, [])

return Page
```